# Difference between native and guest service with Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a bunch of services deploying as guest executables to service fabric and all seems fine.  I was wondering if there was any point in porting the services to be native Fabric Service services.

Looking at the documentation I can't seem to find any benefits of having implementing them as such, am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your services are stateless there is probably no compelling reason to migrate them into native stateless services. It could be different if your services were stateful; in **this** context I mean that they store some state inside the process.

The state in native stateful services is stored redundantly, so your services can cope with node failures. This could increase the resilience of your service. In general, you usually create native services in green field situations and rely on guest executables and containers in migration/hybrid situations.

Answer (score 2):

Guest Executable is missing out on some advanced features but it is up to you to decide if you need them.

**Benefits of running a guest executable in Service Fabric**

*There are several advantages to running a guest executable in a Service Fabric:*

*High availability*. Applications that run in Service Fabric are made highly available. Service Fabric ensures that instances of an application are running.

*Health monitoring*. Service Fabric health monitoring detects if an application is running, and provides diagnostic information if there is a failure.

*Application lifecycle management*. Besides providing upgrades with no downtime, Service Fabric provides automatic rollback to the previous version if there is a bad health event reported during an upgrade.

*Density*. You can run multiple applications in a cluster, which eliminates the need for each application to run on its own hardware.

*Discoverability*: Using REST you can call the Service Fabric Naming service to find other services in the cluster.

I.e. There is something called Stateless Reliable Services - http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/Service-Fabric-Service-Types/

The above link will explain it more.